# Format nested JSON object from Postgres query

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, query-optimization

I want to get a JSON object formatted similar to this:

```
{
  "username": "USERNAME",
  "teamname": "TEAMNAME",
  "logs": [
    {
      "log": {
        "log_id": 29,
        "person_id": 3,
        "activity_id": 3,
        "shoe_id": null,
        "logdate": "2016-11-29",
        "distance": null,
        "activitytime": null,
        "sleep": null,
        "heartrate": null,
        "logtitle": null,
        "description": null
      },
      "activity": "Swim", 
      "comments": {
        "comment_id": 1, 
        "description": "This is a comment", 
        "person_id": 1,
        "log_id": 29
       }
   }]
}
```

Currently I have everything formatted correctly except the comments. Here is the SQL query I am using:

```
SELECT p.username, t.teamname, json_agg(json_build_object('log', l.*, 'comments', c.*, 'activity', a.activity)) as logs
        FROM person_tbl p 
        INNER JOIN log_tbl l ON p.person_id = l.person_id 
        INNER JOIN activity_tbl a ON l.activity_id = a.activity_id 
        INNER JOIN comment_tbl c ON c.log_id = l.log_id
        INNER JOIN person_team_tbl pt ON p.person_id = pt.person_id 
        INNER JOIN team_tbl t on t.team_id = pt.team_id 
        WHERE t.team_id = 5
        AND l.logdate > NOW()::date - 7 
        GROUP BY p.username, t.teamname 
        ORDER BY p.username
```

I'm having trouble getting the comments of each log. Right now, it is returning every comment and repeating the logs (they are not associated).

Also, how could I get this query to return the `username` and `teamname` when everything else is null (like when there are no logs in the past week)?

Comment: to fight `NULL` use `COALESCE(first_not_null,first_not_null)` regarding the rest, it would be nice to have code build somewhere in sandbox, like sqlfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Without an SQLfiddle we do not know what your data (and structure) is so it is difficult to answer your question.
For the NULL case - please modify the WHERE clause like this (deliberately not using COALESCE)

```
WHERE t.team_id = 5 AND (l.logdate IS NULL OR l.logdate > NOW()::date - INTERVAL '7 day')
```